# Customizing Microsoft SmoothStreaming Player 

Tags: c#, asp.net, streaming

I am working on a project that involves the user to view multimedia files like videos or live webcasts thru streaming. I came across the smoothStreaming framework and it was good. But in the player, there is no facility to manually open a video file from the hard disk just like other media players do, so i was wondering that is there anyway to provide this functionality to the player or anyway thru which we can make our own media player on the SMF Framework and then embed it in a webpage.
Please help.